# Execution failed for task ':flutter_facebook_login:verifyReleaseResources'. Having this issue on release mode flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, facebook-login, release

**Debug build** succeed but **release** gives me this error

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':flutter_facebook_login:verifyReleaseResources'.

  > java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
  >   /home/sanwal/Pictures/services/services/build/flutter_facebook_login/intermediates/res/merged/release/values-v28/values-v28.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
  >   /home/sanwal/Pictures/services/services/build/flutter_facebook_login/intermediates/res/merged/release/values-v28/values-v28.xml:11: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
  >   /home/sanwal/Pictures/services/services/build/flutter_facebook_login/intermediates/res/merged/release/values/values.xml:2779: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
  >   /home/sanwal/Pictures/services/services/build/flutter_facebook_login/intermediates/res/merged/release/values/values.xml:2780: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
  >   error: failed linking references.

Comment: it seems like you use flutter_facebook_login *v1.2+*. Please add version of flutter_facebook_login to post

Comment: @KirillMatrosov i am using flutter_facebook_login: ^1.1.1

Comment: It is time to upgrade to *v3.0+*)

Comment: @KirillMatrosov i used flutter_facebook_login:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/roughike/flutter_facebook_login
      ref: '79ff08a'                          instead of  flutter_facebook_login: ^1.1.1 and its working fine ,i found this solution somewhere on internet but i dont know whats the purpose of this and its okay to use or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Switching Flutter channels to latest stable mode.

```
flutter channel
flutter upgrade
```

For example :

```
flutter channel stable
flutter upgrade
```

Reference:
[How to Upgrade flutter version](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/upgrading)!